# Proving identity $\cos^2 a= \sinh^2 b$ if $\sin(a+ib)=\cos b + i\sin b$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

This is my first question on StackExchange. I have some trouble with proving this identity with the following condition:

> If: $\sin(a+ib)= \cos b + i \sin b$
>
> Prove: $\cos^2 (a) = \sinh^2 (b)$

I tried using different methods, but the furthest I've come to is this:

$\sinh^2 (b) = \sin^2 (b)/\cos^2 (a)$

I expanded $\sin(a+ib)$ and rearranged the equation to isolate $\sinh(b)$. I then squared it (to get $\sinh^2 (b)$) and got the above statement.

I would like to know whether I'm on the right track, or if there are any mistakes. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome here. Use mathjax please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
\sin(a+ib)
&=\sin a\cos ib+\cos a\sin ib\\
&=\sin a\cosh b+i\cos a\sinh b\\
&= \cos b + i \sin b
\end{align}
so take real part and imaginary of sides give us
$$\sin a\cosh b= \cos b$$
$$\cos a\sinh b= \sin b$$
then squaring two equations and adding concludes
$$\sin^2 a\cosh^2 b+\cos^2 a\sinh^2 b=1$$
$$(1-\cos^2 a)(1+\sinh^2 b)+\cos^2 a\sinh^2 b=1$$
which gives $\color{blue}{\cos^2 a = \sinh^2 b}$.

Comment: Wow thanks this really seems to make sense!

Comment: Wait for people verify the answer, and give more solutions, then decide about it!

Answer (score 0):

Use that $$\sin(a+bi)=\sin(a)\cosh(b)+i\cos(a)\sinh(b)$$

Comment: I used $\sin(a+bi)=\sin(a)\cosh(b)+i\cos(a)\sinh(b)$ to expand $\sin(a+bi)$, however I got the issue after isolating $\sinh(b)$.

Comment: So your problem is solved? That's nice!

Comment: Thanks Dr. Sonnhard Graubner